# C++ non-blocking TCP Server cannot send a message with more bytes than it received

Tags: tcp, network-programming, winsock, tcpserver

I'm pretty new to network programing. I've written a simple non-blocking TCP Server using winsock2 but it behaves in a weird way that I couldn't find any example of it in previously asked questions.

My server can only send a message with as many bytes as it previously received. For example, if previously it received a "rec_msg", when I try to send "message_to_send" it only sends "message".

I don't if it has any effect but the server is encapsulated with a pure static class. Here are the function via a recieve and send message:

```
int TCPServer_Test::receiveMessage(){
    while(1)
    {   
  memset(recvbuf, 0, DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
  iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
  int err = WSAGetLastError();
  int counter = 0;
  if (iResult > 0) 
  {
            std::cout << "Mesaj Alindi: " << recvbuf << std::endl;
            break;
  }
    else if(err == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
  {
            Sleep(200);
            continue;
    }
  else if (iResult == 0){
    printf("Connection closing...\n");
      return -1;
    }
  else  
  {
    printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    assert(false);
  }
    }
}
```

```
void TCPServer_Test::sendMessage(char* Source){
    strncpy(recvbuf, Source, DEFAULT_BUFLEN);

  iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);

    if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    assert(false);
    } 
    else if (iSendResult == 0) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
    assert(false);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iSendResult);
    }
    memset(recvbuf, 0, sizeof(recvbuf));
}
```

I would appreciate any help directly related or not.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it happens because you are using `iResult` variable that contains amount of data received during previous `recv` call when sending data instead of supplying real size of the data to be sent like this:

```
size_t bytes_count_to_be_send = strlen(Source);
iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, Source, bytes_count_to_be_send, 0);
```

Also notice that there is no real need to copy data into buffer.

Comment: The receiving code is also assuming the received data is null terminated but that is not guaranteed. It should be using the return value of `recv` to limit how much data is written to `std::cout`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Another suspicious thing about `recv` code is that buffer size is expressed first as `DEFAULT_BUFLEN` but then as `recvbuflen`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In the actual code there is not an assumption of null termination, that cout is kind of a replacement aiming to obtain simplification but thank you very very much.

Comment: @VTT I can't believe I missed that, that was the first place that I should've checked. I guess that's the difference of an experienced eye. Thank you very much.